# Display more than 17 lines using phpseclib Interactive shell

Tags: php, linux, ssh, terminal

I'm using phpseclib to access my SSH screen. It works very well with the below code, except I can't display more than 17 rows (40 would be nice).
I tried different things like changing definitions in File/ANSI.php file but without success.

Can it be done with phpseclib files or is it something I have to modify on my (linux/debian) server ?

My file :

```
<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
include('Net/SSH2.php');
include('File/ANSI.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('111.222.33.44');
if (!$ssh->login('user', 'passwd')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

$ansi = new File_ANSI();

$ssh->write("screen -r 27015\n");
$ssh->setTimeout(1);
$ansi->appendString($ssh->read());
echo $ansi->getScreen(); // outputs HTML
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried only this `echo $ssh->read()`

Comment: Blank page. Code is good and works well, it comes from : http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html . I just want to display more lines.

Comment: Maybe you missed this line `$ansi->appendString($ssh->read('username@username:~$'));`

Comment: Same result with this line unfortunately.

Comment: extend you timeout option ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to add rows by modifying Net/SSH2.php :

```
var $windowRows = 24;
```